# Get mysql result in specific json

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter, datatables

i have a issue with my project. 
I am using Codeigniter and its REST Library, Datatables jquery plugin

My Tables

```
Table `order`

+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| id | table_id | waiter_name | date_time           | status  | total |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
|  1 | Table 1  | Waiter 1    | 2016-03-03 12:44:27 | Pending |  1500 |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+

table `orderitems`

+----+----------+-------------+----------+
| id | order_id | food_item   | item_qty |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+
|  1 | 1        | Chicken Fry |        2 |
|  2 | 1        | Beef        |        1 |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+

table `foodinfo`
+----+----------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| id | food_item      | status    | category  | price    |
+----+----------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Chicken Fry    | Available | Meat      |      600 |
|  2 | Beef           | Available | Meat      |      300 |
+----+----------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

my dream datatable

```
ID  TABLE NAME  WAITER NAME DATE AND TIME       FOODS         STATUS    TOTAL
1   Table 1     Waiter 1    1016-03-03 12:44:24 Chicken Fry-2 Pending   1500
                                                Beef       -2
```

my current query

```
$this->db->select('orderitems.*, order.*');
$this->db->from('order');
$this->db->from('orderitems');
$data = $this->db->get()->result_array();
$this->response($data);
```

and json

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "order_id": "1",
    "food_item": "Chicken Fry",
    "item_qty": "2",
    "table_id": "Table 1",
    "waiter_name": "Waiter 1",
    "date_time": "2016-03-03 12:44:27",
    "status": "Pending",
    "total": "1500"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "order_id": "1",
    "food_item": "Beef",
    "item_qty": "2",
    "table_id": "Table 1",
    "waiter_name": "Waiter 1",
    "date_time": "2016-03-03 12:44:27",
    "status": "Pending",
    "total": "1500"
  }
]
```

how do i fetch to this datatable using json and datatable?
codeigniter query builder or  mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

return array to json object.
json_decode or json_encode
I'm sorry, but your problem may not be clear.

Comment: needed to write a sql statement that return data from 3 different sql tables.

Comment: You can try sql( linked query).